# MSQL - Switching rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I've been stuck on the following for quite a while, it seems like it should be relatively simple but I can't quite get my head round it.

Comment: can you tag your database please msql could be many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only getting one row because there is no other column/value to have `PIVOT` produce different groups.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  Doctor
 ,Actor
 ,Singer
 ,Professor
FROM   
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) AS Dummy
   ,Name
   ,Occupation
  FROM 
    Occupations
) o 
PIVOT  
  (  
    MAX(Name) FOR Occupation IN (Doctor, Actor, Singer, Professor)  
  ) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is a row that can be grouped by. `Row_NUMBER` is a good solution

> ```
> CREATE TABLE OCCUPATIONS
>     (Name varchar(255), Occupation varchar(255))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO OCCUPATIONS
>     (Name, Occupation)
> VALUES
>     ('Samantha', 'Doctor'),
>     ('Julia', 'Actor'),
>     ('Maria', 'Actor'),
>     ('Meera', 'Singer'),
>     ('Ashely', 'Professor'),
>     ('Ketty', 'Professor'),
>     ('Christeen', 'Professor'),
>     ('Jane', 'Actor'),
>     ('Jenny', 'Doctor'),
>     ('Priya', 'Singer')
>   ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Row#,Doctor, Actor, Singer, Professor
> from
> (
>   select Name, Occupation,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY name ASC) AS Row#
>   from OCCUPATIONS
> ) d
> pivot
> (
>   max(Name)
>   for Occupation in (Doctor, Actor, Singer, Professor)
>  ) piv;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Row# | Doctor   | Actor | Singer | Professor
> ---: | :------- | :---- | :----- | :--------
>    1 | Jenny    | Jane  | Meera  | Ashely   
>    2 | Samantha | Julia | Priya  | Christeen
>    3 | null     | Maria | null   | Ketty
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE as (SELECT
> Name, Occupation,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY name ASC) AS Row#
> FROM OCCUPATIONS)
> SELECT Row#,Doctor, Actor, Singer, Professor
> from
> (
>   select Name, Occupation,Row#
>   from CTE
> ) d
> pivot
> (
>   max(Name)
>   for Occupation in (Doctor, Actor, Singer, Professor)
>  ) piv;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Row# | Doctor   | Actor | Singer | Professor
> ---: | :------- | :---- | :----- | :--------
>    1 | Jenny    | Jane  | Meera  | Ashely   
>    2 | Samantha | Julia | Priya  | Christeen
>    3 | null     | Maria | null   | Ketty
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=29783adb9927683313afd2124580e62b)*